# How do I test microprofile RestClientBuilder with mockito?

Tags: mockito, microprofile

I'm trying to write up a junit to mock a response from a RestClientBuilder class but what I've had to do seems very convoluted and it's not even working.

In the following code I want the call to the getWorkBean(int) method in IResourceAPI to return a WorkBean object.

My junit method test code so far is:

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder;
import javax.json.bind.Jsonb;
import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

PowerMockito.mockStatic(RestClientBuilder.class);
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilderNewBuilder = Mockito.mock(RestClientBuilder.class);
PowerMockito.when(RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()).thenReturn(restClientBuilderNewBuilder);
RestClientBuilder restClientBuilderBaseURI = Mockito.mock(RestClientBuilder.class);
Mockito.when(restClientBuilderNewBuilder.baseUri(any(URI.class))).thenReturn(restClientBuilderBaseURI);
IResourceAPI resourceAPI = Mockito.mock(IResourceAPI.class);
Mockito.when(restClientBuilderBaseURI.build(IResourceAPI.class)).thenReturn(resourceAPI);
Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok();
Mockito.when(resourceAPI.updateStatus(anyInt(), anyString(), any(WorkBeanAction.class))).thenReturn(responseBuilder.build());
WorkBean workBean = new WorkBean();
Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonb.toJson(workBean).getBytes());
responseBuilder = Response.ok().entity(is);
Mockito.when(resourceAPI.getWorkBean(anyInt())).thenReturn(responseBuilder.build());
```

The exception I'm getting back is:

```
 javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;
```

Answer (score 0):

After much playing around I have a solution.

```
private IWebAppResource webAppResource = Mockito.mock(IWebAppResource.class);

@Before
public void before() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(RestClientBuilder.class);
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilderNewBuilder = Mockito.mock(RestClientBuilder.class);
    PowerMockito.when(RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()).thenReturn(restClientBuilderNewBuilder);
    RestClientBuilder restClientBuilderBaseURI = Mockito.mock(RestClientBuilder.class);
    Mockito.when(restClientBuilderNewBuilder.baseUri(any(URI.class))).thenReturn(restClientBuilderBaseURI);
    Mockito.when(restClientBuilderBaseURI.build(IWebAppResource.class)).thenReturn(webAppResource);
}

@Test
public void doSomethingFunky() {
    Mockito.when(webAppResource.getResource(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(Response.ok().build);
}
```